# Pyspark - Converting the Json type data into tabular form

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks

I have input data like given below in a pyspark dataframe,

[image]

and i want to convert it into the tabular form like below,

[image]

Please help me out as i am pretty new to pyspark.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from_json` along with `schema`

```
df
.withColumn(
   "Results", 
   expr("from_json(Results, 'country string, gender string, city string')")
)
.selectExpr("Results.*")
.show(False)

+-------+------+-------+
|country|gender|city   |
+-------+------+-------+
|Germnay|male  |Hamburg|
|India  |male  |Delhi  |
|France |female|paris  |
|Germnay|male  |Munich |
+-------+------+-------+
```